# integration of Alexa or Similarweb like solutions?

Tags: angularjs, tracking, alexa-skills-kit, pageviews, similarweb

I would like to know if its possible to integrate Alexa or Similarweb like solution in a Angular based application. the fact that angular uses the single web application makes it difficult for this sort of solutions to kwo the PageViews.

is there any way to make angular load html on demand so the page can be trackable by Alexa or any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **window._atrk_fired** to false and call **atrk** method to re-fire the view event, you can place them by adding a listener on **$routeChangeStart** event, it triggered whenever the route changed successfully in angular router.

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    console.log('setting alexa fire value to false');
    window._atrk_fired = false;
    atrk();
});
```